# Catch an array of data and outputting a single row

Tags: php, mysql

I need to have a single row of data "printed out" through php.

So, take this example from w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_select.asp

There is a cicle that goes through all the rows ( in this case, 2) and prints them out. The end result is:

> Peter Griffin
>   Glenn Quagmire

What I want is to be able to select row 1 or 2 (or more) and just have that row of data selected. Then I could say something like (I know this doesent work, just an example):

```
echo $row["Name",2];
```

And get:

> Glenn Quagmire

I believe I have to get a special parameter in mysql_fetch_array, but I cant find it anywhere, and I bet its something really simple. Please help me out, full examples/tutorials/guides links are preferred.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $row[num_row]['id']` ?

Comment: They all print out "M" for some reason. I have a Marco Roberto in there on the Name collum, but it still prints out M on the other, for example ID. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 options. First is edit your SQL query like exmaple below this will return just 2nd row from database.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons" WHERE id = 2);
```

Or during the foreach loop fetch all result into another array.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");

$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $rows[] = $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know mysql doesnt have a function to return the entire query as an array.

So you can switch to using PDO (recommended):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
echo $result[1]['name'];
```

or if you must use the mysql_functions just create an array with the loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
echo $result[1]['name'];
```

Comment: The second method was my solution, but s7anley answered first, So I accepted his answer instead. still, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

fetchall the results into an array and print the row you want.